# C parser for data separated with comma

Tags: c, parsing

What is the most effective way to write a parser in C for data with the following format:

> atr#1,atr#2,...,atr#n
>
> btr#1,btr#2,...,btr#n
>
> ...

Each record is in new line and attributes are separated with comma.

What function should be used? Do you have any examples?

Comment: Why are you using C for this?  Unless you absolutely have to, don't.

Comment: Why are you asking stupid questions instead of answering his question? If he wants/has to write it in C, then answer him using a nice little C function which he can use for this specific purpose. Or has anyone ever suggested you use PHP for desktop app development, BASIC for Linux kernel modules development or Pascal to write iPhone apps?

Comment: Because he's probably not asking the right question.  He may be in which case he will explain why C is a requirement and we can suggest the best tools knowing his application requirements.  But if as I suspect there is no compelling reason to use C, everyone walks away a smarter developer knowing other options to solve this problem in.

Comment: But why is he forced to explain why he is writing this software in C? Why can't you just answer his question without challenging him and forcing him to give explanation? He doesn't want pieces of good advice on good programming practice, he wants to parse a string in C. That's it.

Comment: I've got to agree with both of you. This also may be a homework question so djechlin question, and answer below is more helpful than just giving away a solution without seeing any attempt.

Comment: If this is homework, the language is probably a class requirement. If it's not homework, this is almost certainly a (rather minor) part of a larger program. Switching the rest of the program to another language on the basis of this small part would be the tail wagging the dog.

Comment: @Jerry - we don't know what the application requirements are.  If it's HW it should be tagged as such and it would be prudent not to produce sample code in the interim.  If it's a short task it should be done in a different language.  If it's a large task and not performance/portability sensitive `system("awk/perl/php/etc ...")` is best.  If it's a large task and performance sensitive chances are it's acceptable to link C++ into C.  But these suggestions are off-limits without understanding the application domain.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example code that will read the file sparated by newlines line by line, then split the arguments and print them out (you can easily adapt it to, for example, parse it to an array of array of `char *`s):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    char ptr[1024];
    char *token;

    while (fgets(ptr, 1024, f) != NULL)
    {
        token = strtok(ptr, ",");    
        while(token)
        {
            printf("Token: %s\n", token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated code to use fgets() which is not BSD-specific and NUL-terminates the string.

Comment: You might consider also checking whether `fgets` got a newline, and overwritng that with `0` if it did. But that's practically what I'd have posted.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
/* You need the following includes and defines */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NULL_CHAR 0x0

int parse(char* data) {
    const int LINE_SIZE=255; /* Should be long enough for your unparsed data */
    const int MAX_FIELDS=99; /* Maximum number of fields */
    char  output[MAX_FIELDS][LINE_SIZE];
    int   i;
    int   output_field_count;
    int   output_char_idx;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX_FIELDS; i++) {
        strcpy(output[i], "");
    }
    output_field_count = 0;
    output_char_idx    = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < LINE_SIZE; i++) {
        if ((data[i] != ',')  && 
            (output_field_count    < MAX_FIELDS) && 
            ((output_char_idx+1) < LINE_SIZE)) {

            output[output_field_count][output_char_idx]   = data[i];
            output[output_field_count][output_char_idx+1] = NULL_CHAR;
            output_char_idx++;
        }
        else if (data[i] == ',') {
            output_field_count++;
            output_char_idx = 0;
        }
    }
    output_field_count++;
    output_char_idx = 0;

    printf("OUTPUT FIELD COUNT IS: %d\n", output_field_count);
    for (i = 0; i < output_field_count; i++) {
        printf("FIELD %i IS: %s\n", i, output[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This can be called as follows:

```
char data[500]; /* Should be long enough for your unparsed data */
strcpy(data, "atr#1,atr#2,...,atr#n");
parse(data);
strcpy(data, "btr#1,btr#2,...,btr#n");
parse(data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Pick the right tool for the job.  It's about one line in Perl, Python, or best yet awk.  If you have a compelling reason to use C, please explain in your post - otherwise I think the most judicious answer anyone can give you is to advise you to pick the right tool for the job instead of asking how to do something onerous in a language that's bad at it.

From the command line:

```
tr ',' '\n' < file.txt
```

Will turn the commas into new lines.

Comment: Your suggested use of `tr` will produce an unreadable mess -- you end up with a long list of attributes, but no indication of which are associated with each other (i.e., parts of the same record).

Comment: I have external requirement that I have to write code in C. I can't change it. This the only reason why I asked about C code.

Comment: Are C++ (which compiles into the same objects as C) or system(...) calls an option?

Comment: This is not responsive to the question.